# Tshark will not capture BTLE packets with nRF sniffer

Tags: bluetooth, wireshark, tshark, nrf51, btle

I am having issues using tshark to capture BTLE advertising packets.

The system works very well with Wireshark. However, when I try to run tshark from the command line, it immediately quits and says "0 packets captured."

*Any ideas why it may be working in Wireshark but not in Tshark?*

**Setup:**
I am using the nRF51 DK for the sniffer. This works well in Wireshark (version 2.6.1) as I mentioned. I have a peripheral device that is sending advertising packets that Wireshark easily detects (i.e. I know the hardware works and there are advertising packets being sent).

**Command used:**
After navigating to my Wireshark folder on the command line, I type:

```
tshark -i 6 -a duration:10
```

My nRF sniffer is interface 6. Everything is run on a Windows 10 machine.

**Further Info:**
Tshark works correctly if I try to capture wifi

```
tshark -i 1 -a duration:10
```

where interface 1 is the wifi interface.

Thanks!

Comment: That's indeed kinda weird since Wireshark and tshark are supposed to use the same underlying capture technique. Did you try to run `wireshark -i 6` to make sure you are indeed capturing from the same interface with Wireshark?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, when I run `wireshark -i 6` the interface is the same. 

Sometimes when I try to run the nRF sniffer from the Wireshark GUI, I've noticed that it crashes the first time or two. But afterwards it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Just had confirmation from Nordic that the nRF-sniffer is not currently supported by TShark.